# Does the Samsung Galaxy S7 Universal Unlocked Model (SM-G930UZKAXAA) Have FM Radio?

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s, samsung-galaxy-s7, fm-radio

Does anyone know if the SM-G930UZKAXAA model of the Galaxy S7 has FM radio or not? I've read one review saying that it doesn't, but the review was quite old and the S7 was supposed to have its FM radio capabilities unlocked via an OTA firmware update.

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s7/help/s7-fm-radio-t3321273/page9

Comment: The link was interesting, but didn't address the specific model I mentioned.

Comment: The answer seems to be no; looks like only carrier-specific phones got the update. https://www.reddit.com/r/GalaxyS7/comments/4snz1o/does_the_930u_unlocked_model_have_fm_radio/